# How to create a new object of PostImage Entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

In this [**article**](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2012/02/28/issue-with-plug-in-in-crm-2011.aspx), the author mentioned the following:
Also we were reading post image and updating the post image as it is. This was also creating a problem. **Please create a new object of Entity and then set only those fields which you want to update**. Then update the record.

How to create a new object of PostImage Entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostImage, PreImage and Target all translate to Entity.

e.g.

```
Entity myEntity = new Entity("new_entityname");
myEntity["attriubteName"] = "String Data";
Guid returnId = service.Create(myEntity);
```

The author of the article above suggested that in order to avoid his issues you should not edit and update the context.PostEntityImage["PostImageKey"] directly but map the attributes you want to update to a new Entity like so

```
//context post image Entity
Entity postMessageImage = (Entity)context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];
//new Entity 
Entity myEntity = new Entity("new_entityname");
//map and update
myEntity["attriubteName"] = postMessageImage["attributeName"];
myEntity["attriubteId"] = postMessageImage["attributeId"];
service.Update(myEntity);
```

Comment: We usually declare a post image:                   `postMessageImage = (Entity)context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];`
does this create a new post entity object?